# How can I merge mysql workbench (*.mwb) diagram with git If I know how to make a text representation of it?

Tags: xml, git, mysql-workbench, git-merge

First of all, I'm using git and MySQL Workbench.

I've found that MySQL Workbench diagram (*.mwb file) is just a .zip archive that contains .xml file with description of all tables. The diagram itself is a binary file.

I wrote a simple script that extracts this XML and makes the opposite action. I know how to tell git that I want to use this script to show the difference between two versions of a diagram.

But how can I tell git to make a merge based on next scenario?

1. Take both versions
2. Merge their XML using my script
3. Create new diagram with my script that will override old versions